# appointment scheduling with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going to create a simple appointment scheduling to set appointment for doctor, some thing like this : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I almost know anything about `jQuery` and `JavaScript` but I hope this be a commence to learn more and of course my boss has asked me to do that. Because the created appointment scheduling plugins don't support Persian date, they're useless for me, where should I start from? I wanna set appointment be done bye drag and drop on the surface, like google calendar:

http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html

please suggest me references and some required steps to study and do this.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Just start implementing it. If you get stuck, as here for help. You'll finish faster and learn more that way.

Comment: For any Javascript newbie, I suggest learning more about the core language before relying on frameworks like JQuery. At least learn how JQuery does the stuff it does (or make note of doing so if you're short on time).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to make sure you have a comfortable understanding of server-side language, and saving these calendar dates to a database.  jQuery will only act on client-side, meaning once the browser is "refreshed" you will lose all of your calendar modifications.  Typically how a calendar like that works or can work is based on AJAX calls (as the documentation states on the website you listed)

You will need to know what server-side coding language is being used on the place you wish to host this calendar.  .NET, PHP, Ruby, etc.  You'll need to know how to create and connect to your database(Oracle, MySql, MSSQL, etc) via your server-side code .

So if I were to give you a guide, from a generic standpoint it'd go like this:

1. Identify what language server environment you will be running on (PHP, .NET. Ruby, etc)
2. Create and identify what type of database you will need to use (MySQL, MSSQL, + others).  This is also not simple for a novice developer.  You will need to identify sever host information, and create a database, create users with username(s) and password(s) so that you can access the DB from your code with proper permissions.
3. Locate the folder / location of where all your files will be hosted.  Ex: http://www.eventscalendar.com/youreventscalendergoeshere/
4. Start creating the page template within that folder that will contain your calendar, and drop in all the files that were given to you from that website.
5. Try to get the calendar working (if possible) without any database calls or just empty ajax calls.
6. Once the calendar appears to be working, just not saving anything, then you can start looking into the AJAX calls and how they will need to post and request data from your database.
7. Begin tying ajax + server-side code requests (Post/Get) together until you have confirmed values are now being successfully pended to your database tables.

You will need to learn primarily about jQuery AJAX for this calendar to work:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

It really is not that complicated if you are well acclimated to server-side technology.

**If you do not understand the majority of the terminology I have used in this guide, then this project is probably not for you and too advanced.**

Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Thanks so mush!I know about server-side.how to create that grid and draw rectangle into it by dragging mouse is the thing that sounds complicated to me at first,any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is Persian date\calendar, [momentjs.com](https://momentjs.com/) which is the lib on which `fullcalendar` is based has it supported already